# is there any way for achieving css3 flexible box model in ie9 and below browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I am using css3 flexible box model in my project.

I want to know if there is any way of achieving css3 flexible box model in ie9 and below browsers.

Comment: Have you done a search? You will likely find several javascript based css3 fixes for older browsers.

Comment: yes i have searched and found out that it is possible by using flex.js

But it is not compatible with the latest version of jquery(jquery-1.10.min.js) and is compatible with jquery-1.4.1.min.js.

I would like to know how css3 flexible box model is possible in Ie9 and below browsers using the latest version of jquery.

Any help would be appreciated...